# Is there an easier way to create a mass-storage of mySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

So for my project I am wanting to have a very big database of different car makes, models, and years. My question is that seeing there are going to be a lot of different models for example under the car make Mitsubishi is there a way to create sub-tables / sub-categories in this example under the make Mitsubishi and the same as the years under each model. Sorry for the lack of information but I am very new to mySQL. By the way this is using phpmyadmin with XAMPP.
Here is a screenshot of my progress, all it is are four tables created.

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: You are going the wrong way, car brands should not be column names in your database but values. You need to take a good look on how to model your data so that it fits all brands / years / properties.

Comment: You mean have the column name as the make and have the data as the model / year? Sorry not exactly sure what you mean